# Cannot read from a closed textreader after iterating through IEnumerable once

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've got a problem with "Cannot read from a closed textreader" exception. I have a program which is supposed to get data from file, then do some funny stuff with it and get timespans of everything.

First in one function, I'm loading the data:

```
IEnumerable<string> SomeVariable;
SomeVariable = (from _Something in File.ReadLines(@"file location") select _Something.Split(' ')[1] );
```

In the second function, I run through it once :

```
foreach (var _Something in SomeVariable)
{
    SomeList.Add(_Something);
}
```

Hovewer in the third function, when I try to run throgh it again:

```
foreach (var _Something in SomeVariable)
{
    SomeOtherList.Add(_Something);
}
```

I get the Exception: Cannot read from a closed textreader.
It looks like after one enumeration, it is no longer possible to iterate through SomeVariable.

Is that a problem with IEnumerable itself, or does it have something to do with the File.ReadLines function? I would find it very silly to reload data from file every time I want to iterate through it...

PS. I did the research and I am aware that one of the sollutions is to put both actions in one function, but unfortunatelly this is university program and I have to write it in this way - I have to get separate timespans of both actions.

Comment: That *should* be okay, although it definitely *would* load the file twice. (If you don't want to do that, just use `File.ReadAllLines`.) I can't reproduce your problem, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet, ReadAllLines did the trick :) Hovewer sollution from @Douglas is better in this case, I mark his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are, in fact, reloading the data each time you iterate through your `SomeVariable` enumerable. The `select` clause in your LINQ corresponds to an [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx):

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated [for example] using `foreach`.

This is presumably not your intended behaviour; you would like your `SomeVariable` to be eagerly populated with the resulting list of strings. To achieve this, you can simply call [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) on your enumerable:

```
IList<string> SomeVariable = 
(
    from _Something in File.ReadLines(@"file location") 
    select _Something.Split(' ')[1]
).ToList();
```

Comment: This code would be easier to read without using query expressions at all: `var lines = File.ReadLines("...").Select(line => line.Split(' ')[1]).ToList();`

Comment: That of course makes sense, but I am using pure IEnumerable instead of List<> because I read that it is a faster way and I need this code to go as fast as possible. Is the time profit of using IEnumerable really smaller than the loss of iterating through it?

Comment: @KamilT: Deferred execution is sometimes faster since it avoids the upfront cost of generating the entire list in memory before iterating it. However, in your case, the alternative is to reload the data from disk each time, which will typically be slower. So you're better off pre-populating the list in memory and iterating through that.

Comment: @KamilT, an IList<T> is an IEnumerable<T>. The way you're doing it needs to cache the sequence because the file will be closed by the time you iterate it.
Or you'll need to implement an enumerator over the file.

Answer (score 4):

Although you already have a workaround: this can happen when you forget to `Dispose()` your enumerators, and thus suggests a bug elsewhere in your program.

Here is a short snippet of code that reliably throws an exception for me on the second `foreach`:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"<...>");
var enumerator = lines.GetEnumerator();
foreach (var line in lines) { }
foreach (var line in lines) { }
```

Yes, this will work if you use `File.ReadAllLines(...)` instead, and also if you use `File.ReadLines(...).Select(...).ToList()`. That isn't a complete solution, though: the cause of the exception is that the `enumerator` implements `IDisposable`, but the code forgets to dispose of it.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"<...>");
using (var enumerator = lines.GetEnumerator()) { } // <--- using statement
foreach (var line in lines) { }
foreach (var line in lines) { }
```

You should figure out where in your code that is happening, and fix it similarly. That problem isn't in the code you've shown.

You may of course make sure you only read the file once. But you should consider that separately from the exception you're getting.

Comment: hvd - despite of having my problem already fixed, I appreciate the effort You have put in this answer